# Authentication libraries for flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I’m trying to use the following packages and the app keeps crashing

The libraries are :

1. Fire base auth

   https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth
2. Google sign in
3. Local auth

Comment: Please provide more information. Output of `flutter doctor` so we now what versions you are using. What code causes the error? What is the exact and full error output?

Answer (score 1):

You should make firebase configuration first. You can use this codelabs:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase

Then you can add `firabase_auth` library to pubspec.yaml like this:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter:
  firebase_auth:
```

I recommend you go step by step and don't mess up with google sign in now. Just use email and password authentication for now.